# wso2 JMS JSON to html email without soap enveloppe or with non-xml html

Tags: json, email, wso2, jms, wso2-esb

I would like to send a proper fully dynamic (to, from, body, subject) html email using wso2 4.9.0 from a JMS JSON message.

Here's the SMTP exchange that I want, where all values come from the json message:

```
From: foo <noreply@bar>
Reply-To: foo <noreply@bar>
To: foobar@bar
Cc: bar@bar
Subject: =?UTF8?Q?test;_eacute:_=C3=A9?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Hello =C3=A9<br> and a=
long line is split before 76 chars</body></html>
```

I tried (abbreviated for clarity):

```
mc.setPayloadXML(<ns:text xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">{message}</ns:text>);
// Almost OK but with 4.9.0, the PlainTextFormatter forces the Content-Type to text/plain (I think this is solved in wso2esb 5+)
```

I also tried:

```
//Using in axis2.xml :  <messageFormatter contentType="text/html" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>  
mc.setPayloadXML(<html><body>{message}</body></html>)
// Not ok: Escapes the message
// if it didn't escape the message, it would result in invalid xml anyway
```

I also tried a dozen other combinations but none have worked.

Is it possible to do receive a JSON JMS message, parse it and send a proper html email from the values ?

Answer (score 0):

Following steps will help you to achieve your requriment

1. Once JSON message is read in to ESB ,it will be in SOAP format. Therefore using xslt mediator change the content to you desired output html
2. Set the messsageType and ContentType to text/html
3. Enable text/html message formatter in /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
4. Send the email

This blog contains a sample implementation for email functionality using above approach 
https://medium.com/@Jenananthan/wso2-esb-sending-email-notification-2150f8dca2aa

Comment: Does this allow to send arbitrary content coming from the JSON ? The example blogpost has static content.

Comment: You can change the payload as you want from JSON using the xslt mediator https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/XSLT+Mediator